# One way communication with WEBRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have established 1 to 1 communication using "WEBRTC". Now i want to send video from user A to user B. However, i don't want to send video back from user B to A.

Originally I thought to pass `{ video: false, audio: false }`
as the constraints to the `getUserMedia()` function on the side of the B user. I am not sure if this is the right approach.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: I'm not an expert in webrtc, but your approach seems reasonable as for me.

Answer (score 4):

Don't call getUserMedia nor addTrack (addStream). Make sure you call createOffer with {offerToReceiveAudio: true, offerToReceiveVideo: true}) just in case.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I couldn't find this in the official docs. If someone has a link to the docs. It would be great for future stumblers.

Comment: https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#legacy-configuration-extensions is the spec for that. It  won't be helpful to the casual reader though.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. I've also raised an issue with the MDN team. I spent a lot of time figuring this out. Adding this to MDN docs may save time for others like me.

Comment: Now, as offerToReceive* are deprecated it is advised to use transceivers "recvonly", can someone please explain how do I set one-way video call?

Comment: Check out a working example I wrote for a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77633681/16972333